# Is it possible to restrict an API to only one web interface/app?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, cross-domain

I have a question regarding cross-origin policies.

I have a web app that gets data, usually in JSON format, via ajax.

When the web app initialize, a unique 'key' or 'token' is created from the server via ajax and is sent to the client, as a mean to identify it. The token is sent back on every ajax call for validation purposes. If it is not validated within two hours, a PHP script deletes it, and the user is required to authenticate him/herself again.

If the user sends another ajax call (i.e. if there is *activity* with the associated token), the token sets its expiration for another 2 hours.

On every call, I validate the token and then process the request. Everything works well but my  issue is security-oriented.

Since the token is stored client-side (very crudely, like `window.token = 'YTM0NZomIzI2OTsmIzM0NTueYQ==';`), won't it be possible for malicious users to inspect the code, copy the `JavaScript` including the token, and create another app that will access the same data?

Comment: Yes, and there is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but doesn't it already contain session functionality?

Comment: One method of increasing security is reduce the time a token is valid - this shortens the window malicious users have to do any thing but it doesn't stop them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Since the token is stored client-side (very crudely, like window.token = 'YTM0NZomIzI2OTsmIzM0NTueYQ==';), won't it be possible for malicious users to inspect the code, copy the JavaScript including the token, and create another app that will access the same data?`

Yes.

And possibly even more disturbing to you may be this: **it doesn't even matter how your token is stored client-side** - they'd even be able to login using the same API you expose to your users for logging in. (And if you think you don't have a login API because it's a form-post or something similar, you're fooling yourself - a form post is just as much an "API" as anything else... and can easily be replicated elsewhere).

The cross-domain stuff has very little to do with anything - as that's a client-side restriction of a browser - intended for the user's protection - not yours. I can make any HTTP request I want from a desktop or a server. I can even setup a service which allows me to proxy all requests made to my service over to your service... so the cross-domain security in browsers is of no help to you.